# How to balance CPU cores loading for one process

Tags: cpu-load

When I only ran a real-time process and used 'top' to monitor CPU usage.
I found CPU % usage is not balance for each core and the loading was concentrated specific cores.
How can I achieve this balance?

Comment: Probably not at all if the application you run is not optimized for as many threads as your CPU supports.

Comment: a normal application uses 1 CPU, if it is not written to run with multiple threads on multiple CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to optimize the CPU usage you can try to install **cpulimit** package. It allows to limit the usage of CPU and point the application to use specific core. But all the settings are done by hand, it doesn't have any configuration file. Here is a small [example](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-of-a-process-with-cpulimit-debian-ubuntu) of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have question what software or Kernel extension can manage cores for using.
Something like give for System 1 core, for something else 1 core in 50%.

Comment: This not really an answer to the question.  You should search this site, and if nothing answers your own question, ask it as a question, not post it as an answer.